# HTML: Conflict between style float and nav style?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Why if I use the `float:left` style in my `<ul>` , the `nav bar` becomes very large?

Like this example:

```
 <ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="float:left">
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65qggwch/1/

If I don't use the float the `nav bar` "hide" the elements that exceed the display screen ( exactly the result that I want):

```
 <ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="float:none">
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
   <li>111111----------------------</li>
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65qggwch/

The only problem are that without the `float:left` I have 2 line instead one like the second example.

Comment: Because the float does not fit on the line, it jumps to the next line.

Comment: How i can have both the effect?

Comment: Let me check the Fiddles once again. So you basically want everything on one line, and scrollable using the buttons?

Comment: yes.. the scroll in the fiddle doesn't work because need the c# code .. (it's an asp.net project)

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/65qggwch/2/ Works for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me :/ because i cant set the margin top or will not be longer responsive ..

Comment: This is a tough one, let me try creating a new fiddle with 1 div, and 2 buttons left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you looking for with `flex` elements:

```
/* Create a container that will group its children on a single line */
.containerModule {
    display: flex; 
}

/* The arrow elements should fit to the content */
.sxprova,
.dxprova {
    flex: 0; 
}

/* The nav container should take the available space */
.containerModule > div {
    flex: 1; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/tnhwuqh1/

Be aware of [flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox): IE 10+, and a lot of vendor prefix needed!

Comment: Nice @tzi, this helped me out for future css too! thnx

Comment: On ipad sxprova and dxprova have a strange behavior. they are anchor at the left of the display over and under the containerModule.  any ideas?

Comment: using the -webkit- prefix before flex , solve part of the problem.

Comment: To improve browser support, you should write vendor prefix properties. I advise to use tool to do the conversions, like autoprefixer: [see the project](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or [use it online](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)